# Troubleshooting JMS on weblogic

Tags: jms, weblogic-10.x

My application writes messages to the JMS queue.
I checked with the debugger that everything is written properly.

On the server console, in JMS Monitoring I can see `Message Current` increases in number (from my message).

However, there is a component that is supposed to read messages from the queue and write a file on the server machine, and this is not occurring.
I am not familiar with the JMS yet.

What should I do to troubleshoot this? What should I look for in the configurations, before I know that is is not the 3rd parties, but something with our own application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first step would be to check to see if you have consumers on the JMS queue.

Here's how you can view the consumers on a JMS Destination:

**Step 1 - Select 'JMS Servers' under Services->Messaging from the home page or the left-nav bar:**
[image: Step 1 - Select 'JMS Servers' under Services->Messaging]

**Step 2 - Select the 'JMS Server' for the AdminServer or one of the Managed Servers where your JMS Queue is deployed:**

[image: Step 2 - Select the 'JMS Server' for the AdminServer or one of the Managed Servers where your JMS Queue is deployed]

**Step 3 - Select Monitoring->Active Destinations.  Then select 'Customize this Table' and add the 'Consumers Current' and optionally 'Consumers High' to the table:**
[image: Step 3 - Select Monitoring->Active Destinations]

**Step 4 - Scroll to the right if you cannot see the 'Consumers Current' column.  You should see a count >0 if your application that is supposed to read the message is listening on the queue.  If ConsumersCurrent==0 and ConsumersHigh==0 then no consumers ever connected to the destination to read messages:**

[image: Step 4 - Scroll to the right if you cannot see the 'Consumers Current' column. You should see a count >0 if your application that is supposed to read the message is listening on the queue.]

If there are no consumers, ensure that your application that is supposed to consume the message is deployed and/or configured properly.

Comment: Jeff, Thanks a lot.  I did all this, and here is what I came up with : "Current Consumers =1" and "Consumers High" and "Consumers total" all =1.  Now, You say that I "should see a count >1 if your application that is supposed to read the message is listening on the queue. " Does it mean, that there is something wrong, since I see =1, not > 1? ???

Comment: Thanks, Jeff.  I already found out that there were messages with "bad data" which could not get "consumed", and dealing with jmx separately now.