# How to test JMS receiver in Weblogic

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, weblogic

I have a problem with receiving messages (email to be specific) from the JMS service of weblogic.
Basically I set up the Message Driven Bean in my application which will send a message to JMS when an exception occurs. 
MDB class is well annotated and the JMS JNDI name matches with the weblogic. Also I have Queue connection factory set up.
I know from the sender part then message is sent to JMS (I logged and logging was fine). But I am not sure if weblogic is working correctly and JMS is active in weblogic. (One of the important reasons I am very suspicious about weblogic is that the same MDB class is working on other project on the other weblogic- so the only thing is changed is weblogic)

I already went over following links but couldn't find the solution.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/jms/fund.html

[Troubleshooting JMS on weblogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780706/troubleshooting-jms-on-weblogic)

So to wrap up, what I need is: how I can test that the JMS is properly working on the weblogic

**-- UPDATE --**

here is my MDB Configuration :

```
@MessageDriven(
    messageListenerInterface = MessageListener.class,
    name = "ErrorProcessorMDB",
    mappedName = "jms/AppErrorMessageQueue",
    activationConfig = {
            @ActivationConfigProperty(
                    propertyName = "connectionFactoryJndiName",
                    propertyValue = "jms/QTQueueConnectionFactory"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(
                    propertyName = "destinationType",
                    propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
    })
```

which `jms/AppErrorMessageQueue` is registered as `queue`  and `jms/QTQueueConnectionFactory` is registered as `Connection Factory` in weblogic.

Comment: Are you having some sort of specific error? You should be able to log into the weblogic admin console and go to `JMS Modules -> <your module> -> AppErrorMessageQueue` and click the `Monitoring` tab. You can edit the monitoring table to see if the `Message Total` count is increasing as your application runs. Without a specific error it may be difficult to help more

Comment: @castling `Message Total` count is increasing when an exception is thrown. But no email is sent out.

Comment: I turned on `Logging` to see the messages. But in `Monitoring` when I click `Show Messages` (although there are 14 `Messages Total`) there is no message to show up. I am not sure what I am missing.